# What is the pushforward measure of this random variable?

Tags: probability-theory

Consider $X$ a real-valued random variable defined in the following way:

A fair coin is flipped. If tails, then $X$ takes value -1. If heads, then $X$ takes value in $[0,1]$ uniformly at random. What is the pushforward measure of $X$?

What I can say is that the pushforward measure $\mathbb{P}_X(\{-1\})=1/2$ and $\mathbb{P}_X([0,1])=1/2$ but this doesn't define the pushforward measure for all Borel sets. I am confused about what is $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ for this problem; once I have these it's clear that $\mathbb{P}_X(A) = \mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(A))$ for any Borel set $A$.

Is it correct to write that $\Omega = \{\mbox{heads, tails}\}\times [0,1]$, $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{P}(\{\mbox{heads,tails}\})\times \mathcal{B}([0,1])$ ? But then what should $\mathbb{P}$ be?

EDIT: Okay after thinking a bit more, the pushforward measure is easy to define: for any $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$

$$\mathbb{P}_X(A) = 0.5 \delta_{\{-1\}}(A) + 0.5\lambda(A\cap [0,1])$$

where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure and $\delta_{\{-1\}}$ is the dirac measure. But how to prove this is the case besides just intuiting it? I am still at a loss for defining $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$.

Answer (score 1):

While $P(X \in dx) = \frac{1}{2}\delta_{-1}(dx) + \frac{1}{2}1_{[0, 1]}(x)\,dx$ is the correct answer, I think you are looking for a natural way of rigorously defining $X$ such that you get this as the pushforward measure. There is a very standard method of producing such a random variable using compositions of kernels:

Here $X$ is a mixture, so the natural setting is to have $\Omega = \{0, 1\} \times \mathbb{R}$, and $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{B}(\Omega) = \mathcal{P}(\{0, 1\}) \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Then we define the initial distribution $\mu$ on $\{0, 1\}$:
$$\mu(0) = \frac{1}{2},\hspace{20pt}\mu(1)=\frac{1}{2}.$$
Then we define the transition kernel $\kappa : \{0, 1\} \times \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \to [0, 1]$ from $\{0, 1\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$:
$$\kappa(0, A) = \delta_{-1}(A),$$
$$\kappa(1, A) = \lambda(A \cap [0, 1]).$$
Then the desired distribution on $\{0, 1\} \times \mathbb{R}$ is
$$(\mu \cdot \kappa)(S) = \int \mu(dx)\kappa(x, dy)1_S(x, y).$$
Here on $(\Omega, \mu \cdot \kappa)$, $\omega_1$ is the result of the coin toss, and $\omega_2$ is $X$.

Answer (score 0):

You could model this with the product measure space $\{0,1\}\times[0,1]$ and define the random variable as $X:(s,x)\mapsto(s-1)+s\cdot x$. In this setup, your pushforward measure is correctly calculated. I'm not sure it really makes sense to "prove" your pushforward measure is correct in general since the problem is informally stated; no one is actually flipping a coin and making a decision between two options. However, the standard way to model situations where one thing happens, then the next, and so on, is to take product probability spaces.

Comment: I don't see how someone actually performing the experiment has anything to do with proving rigorously what the pushforward is equal to? If you want, assume I am in my room literally flipping a coin and then running the associated numpy function to generate a uniform random variable depending on the coin flip.

Comment: If I use the product measure space, then what is $\mathbb{P}$?

Comment: @giorginguyen in this example you can define $\mathbb P$ to be the product of Lebesgue measure and discrete prob on $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @giorginguyen Product measure spaces by definition (since they are measure spaces!) have an associated sigma algebra and probability measure (the canonical product algebra and product measure respectively). You running something on numpy or tossing a coin or doing anything physical at all has no mathematical bearing. Depending on your philosophy this is either a good, bad or neutral thing. Unless you are extremely platonist, there is no real sample space you can point and no random variable somehow ‘actually existing’ in real life that is literally performing your coin toss.

Comment: So the problem is informally stated. It does not specify a precise sample space or precise random variable. It just suggests an intuitive description and you are expected to make a reasonable probabilistic model of this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The  thing that matters (from probability point of view) when considering *one* random variable with real values $X$, is the push forward measure on $\mathbb{R}$. If we consider two random variables $X$, $Y$, then it's the pushforward measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$.  If we are dealing with *countably* many random variables, then its' the pushforward measure on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$.  A side note: what about  $(X_t)_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ ? Here things are trickier, since we cannot just look at at the pushforward measure on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ ( one reason why random processes are a step up from basic probability theory).  In any case: the $\Omega$ matters, but not that much, so you do not need to precisely identify it.  It could be in fact $\mathbb{R}$, and $X = Id$.  Of course, if you have two random variables, it cannot be $\mathbb{R}$ any longer...

Note:  no specialist here, just an opinion.

Comment: But what is $\mathbb{P}$ in any of these examples? Surely to define the pushforward I need to know what $\mathbb{P}$ is on the initial probability space?

Comment: @giorgi nguyen: Roll a die, if you get $i$ even then $X$ takes value $i$, if $i$ odd then $X$ is uniform in $[i,i+1]$.  In fact that says nothing about $\Omega$, but all about the pushforward measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Surely when you say roll a die you are implying some measure $\mathbb{P}$, for instance that the die is fair must imply something about it.

Answer (score 0):

FShrike’s answer mostly says it all, but if you really wanted a sample space that captured every potential outcome as a single point, without adding other uninterpretable outcomes, you could let $\Omega=(\{\text{heads}\}\times [0,1])\cup \{\text{tails}\}$, using the product and disjoint union topologies. Then your $\sigma$-algebra is the Borel sets of $\Omega$, and you can define $\mathbb P$ in the obvious way as $\mathbb P(\{\text{heads}\}\times A)=\frac{1}{2}\lambda(A)$, $\mathbb P(\{\text{tails}\})=\frac{1}{2}$, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure.